# How to get to another application's specific page

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a widget application, which I have made clickable to reach to another application. However, I am stuck on how to get to a specific `fragment` in my application. My code is making me open the application, but I want to open a specific page. For that, I tried to put the package of the class I want to be displayed but I got a `null pointer exception` on the category launcher line. Is it possible? This is my code so far. TIA

```
                  Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                  PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
                  in = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.playup.android");
                  in.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0 /* no requestCode */, in, 0 /* no flags */);
```

Comment: Use the published API of the other application, or its documented `Intent` structure to get to your desired activity. If the other application does not have such documentation,and you did not write the other application, do not attempt to open up any activity other than its main one.